# Switch Case not showing correct results

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Here is my script

```lavascript
var marks = 11;
switch (marks) {
  case (marks < 20):
    console.log('Yes Freaking Failed');
    break;
  case (marks > 20):
    console.log('Ahh Its Ok');
    break;
  case (marks > 80):
    console.log('Whooping');
    break;
  default:
    console.log('Cant say u maybe Flunked');
    break;
}
```

I think it should display `'Yes Freaking Failed'` because the marks are less than 20. But it shows `'Cant say u maybe Flunked'`

Why is that?

Comment: you can't have conditional statements in switch case.. use if else

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7qhxh31m/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you write

```
switch (x) {
case(y):
    ...
}
```

it's equivalent to testing

```
if (x == y) {
    ...
}
```

So

```
case (marks < 20):
```

means:

```
if (marks == (marks < 20)) {
```

You can't use `case` for range tests like this, you need to use a series of `if/else if`:

```
if (marks < 20) {
    console.log('Yes Freaking Failed');
} else if (marks < 80) {
    console.log('Ahh Its OK');
} else {
    console.log('Whooping');
}
```

Also notice that if it worked the way you thought, it could never execute `marks > 80`, because that would also match `marks > 20`, and the first matching case is always executed.

There's no need for the `Cant say u maybe flunked` case, because there are no other possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it's not possible. Javascript makes it so.

If you need to compare, use if/else if/else.

Switch cases are for when you know you will have specific values.

```
var marks=11;
    switch(marks){
        case (11):
        console.log('It would go in here');
        break;
        case (42):
        console.log('If equal to 42');
        break;
        case (80):
        console.log('if equal to 80.');            
        break;

        default:
        console.log('Cant say u maybe Flunked');
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
var marks=11;
switch(marks){
    case (true):
    console.log('Yes Freaking Failed');
    break;
    case (false):
    console.log('Ahh Its Ok');
    break;
    case (false):
    console.log('Whooping');    
    break;          
    default:
    console.log('Cant say u maybe Flunked');
    break;
}
```

`marks` is not `true` and is not `false` - so `switch` goes to `default`.

Answer (score 0):

when you use switch statement, you are evaluating marks and compare the values of marks with the cases. And you have the following cases: 1, 0, 0, default. It's because (marks<20) evaluates to true which is 1, and the other two are false, which is 0. 
So you should do if and else if in your case.